# relationships in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I know how to create one to many, many to many relationships in SQL Server, but is it possible to create one to one relationship? And is it possible to create 1 to 0 or 1 relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just put `PRIMARY KEY`s of both entities into a link table, defining a `UNIQUE` key on both entities:

```
myrel(entityA, entityB, UNIQUE(entityA), UNIQUE(entityB))
```

Thus, if `entityA = 1` is related to `entityB = 2`:

```
entityA  entityB
      1        2
```

, you can relate neither `entityA = 1` to any other `entityB`, nor an `entityB = 2` to any other `entityA`.

If you relation is *symmetrical* (i. e. `entityA` and `entityB` belong to same domain and relating `entityA` to `entityB` also means relating `entityB` to `entityA`), then define an additional `CHECK` constrant:

```
entityA  entityB

UNIQUE(entityA)
UNIQUE(entityB)
CHECK(entityA < entityB)
```

and transform the normalized relation to a canonical one with this query:

```
SELECT entityA, entityB
FROM   myrel
UNION
SELECT entityB, entityA
FROM   myrel
```

This is a `(0-1):(0-1)` relation.

If you want it to be a `1:1` relation, define this table to be a domain for both `entityA` and `entityB`:

```
myrel(entityA, entityB, UNIQUE(entityA), UNIQUE(entityB))
A(id, PRIMARY KEY(id), FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES myrel (entityA))
B(id, PRIMARY KEY(id), FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES myrel (entityB))
```

By removing the `FOREIGN KEY` from either table's definition, you change the corresponding part of the relationship from `1` to `(0-1)`.

Comment: what about 1 to 0 or 1 relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:
1) a pk-pk 1:1 relationship. Table A and B have both a PK. Create an FK from the B PK to the PK of A. This makes 'B' the FK side of the 1:1 relationship

or

2) an FK/UC-PK 1:1 relationship. Table A has a PK and table B has a foreign key to A, but the FK in B is not on the PK of B. Now create a UC on the FK field(s) in B.

Comment: what about 1 to 0 or 1 relationship?

Comment: In method 1, how do you insert a new entry into both A and B?  And isn't Method 2 ultimately a "1 to 0 or 1" relationship?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: make the FK nullable.

@Jonathan: Method 1 is easy to insert. As B depends on A, you first insert the row in A, then the row in B. A doesn't point to B, B just points to A. Method 2 isn't a 1..0..1 relationship, if you make the FK not nullable, it only gets optional if the FK side is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make the Primary or alternate Key in the dependant table a Foreign Key to the Primary Key in the parent Table.

Comment: what about 1 to 0 or 1 relationship?

Comment: What I described is a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship.  There does not have to be a record in the child table for every row in the parent table...

Answer (score 0):

Yes

TableA
id PK

TableB
id PK FK TableA

Comment: What about modifying. For example room relates 1:1 to manager, Some manager has been fired, how to update?

Comment: To manage it you need cascading either db level or on your data access layer level.

Answer (score 0):

It's fun but it my favorite questions on interview.

So You have table A, B corresponding each of them has primary key A_ID, B_ID. Add foreign key to any. Let it be B: A_REF, so you just need add unique constraint onto A_REF.

Comment: +1 because you're right, but can you explain a little more verbosely?

Comment: what about 1 to 0 or 1 relationship?

Comment: Table A id is a PK (which automatically makes it unique) and is a FK to table B id which also is a PK (which automatically makes it unique).